# How do I do Eager loading with includes but limiting whats loaded by using scope that includes parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Ok So I have the following models

```
Class Company < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many customers
active?

Class Customers < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :Company
has_one :account

Class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :Customer
has_many :invoices

Class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :account
has_many :line_items
invoice_date

Class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to:Invoice
```

What I need to do is retrieve:
All active Companies who have customers and some invoices for those customers

Here is the rub: 
Since each customer can have a huge amount of invoices I want to only return lets say the invoice for April 1st 2012.

What I want to do is use includes combined with a scope or method set on the model to limit the amount of invoices that are returned.

My Model would contain the scope:

```
Class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :account
scope :for_the_day_of, lambda{|invoice_date|where('invoices.invoice_date',invoice_date }
```

So now I can write something like this:

```
invoice = Invoice.for_the_day_of(Date.today).first
```

what I really want to do with it is something like:

```
comapanies = Company.where(:active => true)
.includes(:merchants => [:billing_account => 
[:invoices => for_the_day_of(Date.today) => :invoice_line_items]])
```

I don't know if this is possible in active record or maybe I'm just thinking about the problem wrong

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need scopes that you have access from another model and some subqueries functionality.
I'm using gem [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) for this propose. This is great gem, that expand Active Records functionality.